# Compare Validator doesn't work in password mode

Tags: asp.net, validation

I've got two textboxes (`NewPassword` and `ConfirmedPassword`) with `TextMode=Password` and Compare Validator doesn't detect if they aren't equal. `Page.IsValid` is always true. If I remove password mode from my textboxes, everything works and validator show message, that they aren't equal. How can I make this work in password mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should show us your code since this works as expected:

```
  <asp:TextBox id="NewPassword" runat="server"
      TextMode="Password" />

  <asp:TextBox id="ConfirmedPassword" runat="server"
      TextMode="Password" />

  <asp:CompareValidator id="comparePasswords" 
      runat="server"
      ControlToCompare="NewPassword"
      ControlToValidate="ConfirmedPassword"
      ErrorMessage="Your passwords do not match up!"
      Display="Dynamic" />
```

Maybe you've mixed up `ControlToCompare` and/or `ControlToValidate`.

Comment: First I had `ConfirmedPassword` assigned to ControlToCompare and `NewPassword` to ControlToValidate, now I've changed it as you wrote in your example and it works. I thought it doesn't matter where each textbox is assigned, if they must be equal :D